# what to do with non-pip requirement in requirements.txt

Tags: python, spacy

So I recently moved my NLP application over to a new machine. Added the same python environment with pyenv as the old machine and installed with pip all the dependencies. Then there was a 'dependency' of sorts that is not installed by pip, maybe 'model' is a better word for it. The command that installed it is:

```
python -m spacy.en.download
```

Now, I'm wanting to note that somewhere in my repository so if one day I or someone else goes to install the whole thing on another PC it's there, noted in accordance with Python style guides and conventions.

On [this](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/models) spaCy page it says that it can go in requirements.txt. While

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

will create a file this won't capture the correct procedure to install that requirement. One day someone will run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

..and will still run into the same error as I did

```
Warning: no model found for 'en'

Only loading the 'en' tokenizer.
```

Does anyone know how to correctly list this requirement in requirements.txt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

spaCy's data packages are actually wrapped as `pip` packages for exactly this reason --- they have a `setup.py`, a version, etc. It's just that they're large and so aren't distributed via PyPi. You can point to a URL or a file-path in your requirements.txt, though:

https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-1.2.0/en_core_web_sm-1.2.0.tar.gz

Lots of production users host their own PyPi servers (so they're not downloading arbitrary code from the internet). You can distribute the models via a PyPi warehouse if you do that.

Comment: Thanks I just wanted to comply with the rules as this thing might soon go into a blog or somewhere people will see it and am still learning about requirements.txt, setup.py. PyPi warehouse is a new one, hadn't hear of that..

Comment: I get `An error occurred while installing https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-1.2.0/en_core_web_sm-1.2.0.tar.gz#egg=en-core-web-sm! Will try again` when I add this to my `requirements.txt` file.