# en-core-web-sm module error - Serverless deployment AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, spacy

I am using SpaCy's `en-core-web-sm` in my Python AWS Lambda. I ran `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to get all the dependencies in the `requirements.txt` file. `en-core-web-sm==2.1.0` is one of the lines in the file.

When I try to make a serverless deployment, I get `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement en-core-web-sm==2.1.0 (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for en-core-web-sm==2.1.0` .

Even though I am not using Heroku, I followed [Heroku Deployment Error: No matching distribution found for en-core-web-sm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028694/heroku-deployment-error-no-matching-distribution-found-for-en-core-web-sm) and added the line `https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm==2.1.0` in my `requirements.txt` file only to get `Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: XxX-XxX)`

How to wire up `en-web-core-sm` to my Lambda?

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286663/what-to-do-with-non-pip-requirement-in-requirements-txt) will help you.

Comment: @ChandanGupta: I get `An error occurred while installing https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-1.2.0/en_core_web_sm-1.2.0.tar.gz#egg=en-core-web-sm! Will try again` when I add this to my `requirements.txt` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the advantage of the model being a separate component to the library and uploaded the model in an S3 bucket. Before initialising spaCy, I download the model from S3. This is accomplished by the method below.

```
def download_dir(dist, local, bucket):
    client = get_boto3_client('s3', lambda n: boto3.client('s3'))
    resource = get_boto3_client('s3r', lambda n: boto3.resource('s3'))

    paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')
    for result in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Delimiter='/', Prefix=dist):
        if result.get('CommonPrefixes') is not None:
            for subdir in result.get('CommonPrefixes'):
                download_dir(subdir.get('Prefix'), local, bucket)
        if result.get('Contents') is not None:
            for file in result.get('Contents'):

                if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(local + os.sep + file.get('Key'))):
                    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(local + os.sep + file.get('Key')))
                dest_path = local + os.sep + file.get('Key')

                if not dest_path.endswith('/'):
                    resource.meta.client.download_file(bucket, file.get('Key'), dest_path)
```

And the code using spaCy looks like this:

```
import spacy
if not os.path.isdir(f'/tmp/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0'):
       download_dir(lang, '/tmp', mapping_bucket)
spacy.util.set_data_path('/tmp')

nlp = spacy.load(f'/tmp/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0')
doc = nlp(spacy_input)
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.label_)
```

Comment: @Nagarajan Shanmuganathan, Is this answer helpful for you?

Comment: I started using a 3P Lambda [Layer](https://www.keithrozario.com/2019/04/spacy-in-a-lambda-layer.html) which had SpaCy bundled in it since I wanted a quick deployment and that avoided all the overhead of managing the files on S3 and bootstrapping.

Comment: Where does `get_boto3_client` bit come from? I get the error: `NameError: name 'get_boto3_client' is not defined`. I've tried importing it from boto3 but no luck